# Bar chart not showing complete dataset

Tags: csv, d3.js

Not sure why my code is cutting off data at 2011-08-22  for each of the coins. The .csv file has a date range from:

American Eagle,2014-12-02,1260 - American Eagle,2009-12-02,1266.54  the dates are the same for each of the coin names grouped by coin name.

Please view the chart here: http://dvl.thomascooper.com/goldcoins/goldbar.html 
jsfiddle is not working for me with the .csv file (cors issue on my shared server).
when you hover the gold bars you will see the tooltip cuts off at 
2011-08-22. You can view the .csv data in the browser console.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you
T6

Comment: If your objective is to visualize how the value of these different coins compare to each other over a historical time period, the most intuitive way to display this (to me anyway), would be using a multi-series line chart. Each coin would be a different series (line), the y axis would be based on coin value, and the x axis would be based on the dates you have measurements for. Excellent example to start with here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

 You can add some flare to this type of graph in a number of ways - here's one example: http://fundvis-ywng.rhcloud.com/JPMProvident.html

Comment: Thank you Peter! I made a nice multi-line chart based on a bl.ocks example and it worked really well. Your jpm chart is awesome. I got so into data binding and playing with the bar chart that I failed to see the bigger picture of  proper chart type selection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, happy to help, and glad the line chart worked well for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your barchar isn't correct, you max value is :

```
Mexican Peso    2011/8/23   2261.22
Mexican Peso    2011/8/22   2293.17
```

Any other value less than these and after date of 2011/8/23 can not be shown there, they are indeed be drawn there.
You can draw a stackbar with total counts as yAxis to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input huan!  To help me better understand. I should use a stacked bar chart instead of a plain bar Chart?

Comment: I think so. stack bar chart:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208           Grouped Bar Chart is also a choice:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051